# Why is one query returning the right value, but the one right after it returns 0?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here's my code:

```
            $stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT wins FROM users WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT losses FROM users WHERE id = ?");

            $stmt1->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["id"]);
            $stmt2->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["id"]);

            $stmt1->bind_result($db_wins);
            $stmt2->bind_result($db_losses);

            $stmt1->execute();
            $stmt2->execute();

            $stmt1->fetch();
            $stmt2->fetch();

            // Print out user scores
            echo "<p><strong>User:</strong> " . $_SESSION["username"] . "</p>\n";
            echo "<p><strong>Wins:</strong> " . $db_wins . "</p>\n";
            echo "<p><strong>Losses:</strong> " . $db_losses . "</p>\n";
```

Everything prints correctly except losses, which prints 0 when it should print the value in the table.

Points of note:

- It prints the value as intended a little down the page, but without using preparation statements.
- If I run it in phpMyAdmin (the query that returns 0) or Sequel Pro it returns the correct loss value.

Comment: Why not `SELECT wins, losses FROM users WHERE id = ?` and then get the two fields from your result array?

Comment: Almost always better to fetch two columns in one query than two queries to fetch different columns.

Comment: Brilliant, Kolink. Doh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment from Kolink above, but I think that changing your code to the following should also make the issue go away. The [PHP pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) offer the following alternative though, maybe that can also be used in your case? EDIT: Obviously you can still encorperate the bind_param into this.

```
/* prepare statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name LIMIT 5")) {
   $stmt->execute();

   /* bind variables to prepared statement */
   $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);

   /* fetch values */
   while ($stmt->fetch()) {
       printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
   }

   /* close statement */
   $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `fetch()` with no arguments, so by default it should be returning the data you want. If you pass in `PDO::FETCH_BOUND` that might trigger the bind operation as [per the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to count ($db_losses) instead of just printing de variable ?

Sometimes the pointer in Mysql array isn't at the 1rst element and stay on the last element of the array that print 0 !

Try to use reset() function on your array. http://www.php.net/reset